# Code not being accepted by online judge

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, structure, selection-sort

I have just finished beginner level programming and am trying out a problem from an olympiad. its relatively easy but i am getting only one correct answer from 10 inputs by an online judge.
Here's the link:http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/SORTROWS

BTW i am using an external file for input to make entering data easier. 
any help or tips will be apprecieted.
can anyone suggest a method to test random data quickly? i cant afford to make another program to do that during a competition.
The online judge uses g++ compiler

now here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("test.txt");
    struct ac
    {
           int arr[51];
           int size;
    }ar[1000];  //represents each line
    int i,j,n,m,in,pos,k;
    ac small;
    ifs>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
           for(j=0;;j++)
           {
                 ifs>>in;
                 ar[i].arr[j]=in;
                 if(in==-1)
                 {
                      ar[i].size=j+1;
                      break;
                 }
           }

    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)   //using selection sort
    {
           pos=i;
           small=ar[i];
           for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
           {
                 for(k=0;k<ar[j].size&&k<ar[i].size;k++)
                 {
                      if(ar[i].arr[k]>ar[j].arr[k])
                      {
                              small=ar[j];
                              pos=j;
                      }
                      else if(ar[i].arr[k]==ar[j].arr[k]) //to continue checking
                              continue;
                              break;
                 }
           }
           ar[pos]=ar[i];
           ar[i]=small;
           for(m=0;m<ar[i].size-1;m++)
                 cout<<ar[i].arr[m]<<' ';
           cout<<'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for one, for(m=0;m<ar[i].size-1;m++) You are not outputting the last element.

Comment: its because last element is not supposed to be printed.

Comment: @Sumedh If you are talking about the last -1 entry then I think a better way would be to not input that entry in the array and just reject it.

Comment: @Abhishek, it just denotes the end of the line.A programmar might not need that, but the program user might be happy with that format...regardless of all that, the problem question requires it to be that way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this as a separate answer because it is totally different from my previous one.

A better method to approach this problem would be to use vector of std::arrays

```
std::vector< std::array<int> >
```

This way you can treat each array as a single entity and as per [this C++ Link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp) the comparison operator would straightaway work like in a 1D array.

**You do not need to loop through the sub-arrays yourself.**

Of course you will need C++11 features to be enabled in the compiler.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i am quite new to vectors so this was quite helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should compare each sub-array with the current smallest sub-array not with the ith sub-array.

```
for(k=0;k<ar[j].size&&k<ar[i].size;k++)
{
  if(ar[i].arr[k]>ar[j].arr[k])
```

Try changing this to:

```
for(k=0;k<ar[j].size&&k<ar[pos].size;k++)
{
  if(ar[pos].arr[k]>ar[j].arr[k])
```

Also, IMO you should not enter the last -1 entry in you arrays.

```
ar[i].arr[j]=in;
if(in==-1)
{
  ar[i].size=j+1;
  break;
}
```

Change this to:

```
if ( in != -1 ) {
  ar[i].arr[j]=in;
  ar[i].size=j+1;
}
else
{ 
  break;
}
```

Then you will have to change

```
for(m=0;m<ar[i].size-1;m++)
```

to

```
for(m=0;m<ar[i].size;m++)
```

Comment: okay i got it. Must say it was a ridiculously careless mistake by me

Answer (score 0):

This is more a comment than an answer, I'm posting it as such for the better formatting possibilities. In addition to what others have said:

```
else if(ar[i].arr[k]==ar[j].arr[k]) //to continue checking
    continue;
    break;
```

You are aware that the `break`will be executed in case the comparison is false, right? It would be better to format this in a way to emphasize this if it is intentional, e.g.:

```
else if(ar[i].arr[k]==ar[j].arr[k]) //to continue checking
    continue;

break;
```

or even with an explicit `else`.

Comment: yes that was just an accident while pasting the code in the question. will avoid these blunders from now on